# How can I finish the edges of recessed boxes in a drywall stair wall?

Tags: drywall

I'm going to cut into the double drywall on the sidewall as you walk down our basement stairs and build some shoe storage out of plywood to attach to the wall, so it's like a cutout into the wall.

I'm not sure about what to do where the plywood box meets the drywall wall. I could have either be the exposed edge. All I can think of is to have the plywood be the exposed edge and then cover with moulding.

Other ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are spot on. You'd cut out the drywall, insert and attach the box with the front flush to the wall, and then cover with trim/molding.

Comment: Right. You can't really go the other way because drywall doesn't cut cleanly. You'd need to caulk against the trim to close the joint.

Comment: There's also finishing with a [J trim](https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.d400-metal--j-trim-12-board-x-10-feet.1000181113.html) if all you want to see are the box lines.